# How to import a scheduled task automatically from an XML file?

Tags: xml, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a scheduled task in Windows 7. The task is running perfectly well on my computer.

I have also exported the task to an XML file and want to create the same task on another computer automatically. How can I import the XML file pragmatically  in Task Scheduler on the second computer?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the **schtasks** command:

```
schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]] /XML <xmlfile> /TN <taskname>
```

For more help type `schtasks /Create /?` at the command prompt.